# iOS corebluetooth:Delegate method know weather peripheral connection is out of range and inside of range

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am working on the corebluetooth framework in iOS. My central connection is iPhone and  I have  to connect to peripheral device.

1) Are we able to find whether peripheral device is inside or out of range ?

2) How much data can be received or sent through bluetooth app?

3) We should give The service uuid's and characteristic uuid's at first time itself or these info will be get after discovering by central device?

4) Can we able to know the battery status of peripheral device? if so there is any delegate method present in framework itself

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer this [Link](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928623/read-data-from-ble-device) [Link 3](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741)

Download this source code to check 
-Shows live accelerometer data

-Shows live battery level data

-Shows live button data

-Can sound buzzer when button is pressed

[BLE SOURCE CODE](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/File:TI-iPhone4SBLE-Demo_rev2.zip)

Hopes Its useful for you.

Comment: Better use the Apple one..I just sent the sample,

Comment: Give me sometime I will find for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. If device goes out of range of mobile client, the BT will be disconnected. The iOS device needs to auto reconnect upon coming back in range within a certain period say 1hr. Beyond that the user will manually connect to the device.Can we do this.

Comment: https://redbearlab.zendesk.com/entries/43749557-ios-app-connect-to-BLE-automatically

Comment: But I don't think reconnect is possible so far.But I'm not sure