# How to get battery life of Bluetooth Low Energy in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am able to get a value for BLE battery life with the help of following questions:

[Read data from BLE device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928623/read-data-from-ble-device)

[Reading a BLE Peripheral Characteristic and checking its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894363/reading-a-ble-peripheral-characteristic-and-checking-its-value)

But I am not sure if It returns the right value? It returns 18, and I am also not sure about the maximum number to determine the battery life based on percentage. Does it mean 18 hours?

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    print("-CBService is: \(service.uuid.description)")

    if compare(service.uuid, uuid2: CBUUID(string:BluetoothConstants.TI_KEYFOB_BATT_SERVICE_UUID)) {
        print("Battyer Life determination")

        for characteristic: CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics! {
            if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: BluetoothConstants.TI_KEYFOB_LEVEL_SERVICE_UUID) {
                print(characteristic.properties.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following line is print for characterstic:

```
CBCharacteristic: 0x1c00be8a0, UUID = Battery Level, properties =
0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>
```

I tried most of the answers here but they are not working for Swift 4.

Comment: The standard battery level characteristic is described here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml - It is a percentage, so 0x12 indicates 18% battery

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. it means I am not getting the right value as I recently changed the battery and I should get above 90%.

Comment: I did find some code that referred to `TI_KEYFOB_LEVEL_SERVICE_UUID` which was defined as 0xFFF1, but I couldn't find any mention of this in the TI sensortag document.  I would try with the standard battery service of 0x180F and the standard battery characteristic 0x2A19 and see what you get

Comment: @Paulw11 I printed the value of it `print(characteristic.value!)` and it returns `1 byte` which is Data. I am trying to  use `var batlevel = 0
characteristic.value.getBytes(batlevel, length: TI_KEYFOB_LEVEL_SERVICE_READ_LEN)
batteryLevel = Float(batlevel)
` but looks like it dosn't work for Swift 4.

Comment: "The Battery Service exposes the Battery Level of the coin cell in V.BTTN.
Battery level are reported as a percentage, e.g. 5C is 92%."

Comment: It is a single byte Int8; so 0x12 is 18 decimal, which is 18%. Either you aren't reading the correct battery service/characterstic, the battery level hardware isn't reading correctly or your new battery is low.  What is the definition of `TI_KEYFOB_BATT_SERVICE_UUID` ?

Comment: It is `0x180F`. And I am getting `Battery Life` when I print it.

Comment: I changed the battery. It is 18 for another one as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about Swift 4, but here's how I figured it out using Swift 5.  The value in the characteristic.properties is not the battery level.  You need to request a read from the device on the Battery Level characteristic (0x2A19):

```
if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: "0x2A19") {
   peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
}
```

Then you'll need to add the didUpdateValueFor as part of your CBPeripheralDelegate as well:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
   print("Battery level: \(characteristic.value![0])")
}
```

I tested this with an old 3V that was at 2.76V (which is pretty much considered dead) and it gave me a value of 3.  Then I put in a new battery and it gave me a value of 100.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
func peripheral(
    _ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
    didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
    error: Error?
) {
    if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A19" {
        print("Battery level: \(characteristic.value![0])")
    }
}
    
func peripheral(
    _ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
    didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,
    error: Error?
) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Error discovering service characteristics: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    for newChar: CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics! {
        peripheral.readValue(for: newChar)
        if newChar.properties.rawValue == 0x12 {
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: newChar)
            print("characteristicValues",newChar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get the battery percentage

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: 2A19 is for the battery characteristics peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: newChar) this is for notifying the values that means we can get the battery values